# Accessing bean properties with getters giving errors

Tags: drools

If I try to access properties of a java bean with getters it gives me errors, while using bean property directly works properly. I understand that using bean properties directly is the recommended way as stated in [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e5482). However I prefer to use getters for some specific reasons in this case.

Here is the rule file and the errors I am getting. Would appreciate any clues on why I get this strange behavior.

*Rule file*

```
package test.rules

import java.lang.Math;
import test.MatFact;
import test.MatHotelAlternative;
import test.MatHotelItem;


dialect "mvel"

rule "0"
salience 0
when
    $item: MatHotelItem()
    $alt: MatHotelAlternative( processed == false
        && (getStarRating() == "*")
    )
then
    modify ($alt) {
        // some actions here
    }
end
```

*Errors*

```
[16,26]: [ERR 101] Line 16:26 no viable alternative at input ')' in rule "0" in pattern MatHotelAlternative
[16,28]: [ERR 102] Line 16:28 mismatched input '==' expecting ')' in rule "0" in pattern MatHotelAlternative
[17,1]: [ERR 102] Line 17:1 mismatched input ')' expecting 'then' in rule "0"
```

*Related classes*

MatHotelAlternative

```
public class MatHotelAlternative extends MatItemAlternative<Hotel>
{
    public String getStarRating()
    {
        return alternative.getStarRating();
    }
}
```

MatItemAlternative

```
public abstract class MatItemAlternative<T extends HolidayItem>
{
    private boolean processed;
    protected T alternative;

    public MatItemAlternative( T alternative )
    {
        this.alternative = alternative;
    }

    public boolean isProcessed()
    {
        return processed;
    }

    public void setProcessed( boolean processed )
    {
        this.processed = processed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be certain, the rule works perfectly fine if you use the bean properties instead of explicit getter? Your post does not include the fact, does it have the properties you are referring to? Can you post that as well?

Comment: @JAndy: This is indeed the case. I have added the related java classes. Would much appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the class loader has been loading Drools 5.1.1 and this seems to be the cause of the problem. The problem was resolved when I switched to Drools 5.5.0 Final.

Answer (score 0):

this should work: 
$alt: MatHotelAlternative( processed == false, starRating == "*")

can you try with that?
Which errors did you get with this alternative?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This infact works as I mentioned in the question. I'm just wondering why it does not when I use gettets.